# Replaced optical drive with SSD in caddy, but BIOS freezes (Acer Aspire 5740-5847)

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, ssd, bios, acer-aspire

I tried replacing the optical drive of my [Acer Aspire 5740-5847](http://www.cnet.com/laptops/acer-aspire-5740-5847/4507-3121_7-33973216.html) with an Intel SSD (inside [a caddy](http://www.ebay.com/itm/2nd-HDD-SSD-hard-drive-Caddy-for-Acer-5532-5535-5536-5541g-5552g-5560-5740g-/360640412488) I bought from ebay), but then the BIOS freezes, after showing that it has detected both hard drives - it displays something like:

```
Fixed Disk Intel <some serial number>
Fixed Disk Hitachi <some serial number>
```

Both the SSD and the original hard drive work fine when put in the normal hard drive slot in the laptop, and both cause the BIOS to freeze when put in the caddy.

I tried plugging the caddy when Windows was already loaded, but it wasn't detected.

Is there anything I can try to fix that problem (updating BIOS or something), and is it a known problem for my laptop model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updating the BIOS to version 1.28 fixed it for me. My BIOS was version 1.16. I downloaded the new BIOS from [Acer's support site](http://us.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/drivers).

Comment: I had the same problem with Acer Aspire 4741G. The HD caddy in the DVD slot worked in principle, but the original BIOS (1.07) froze on boot.

Upgrading the BIOS to version 1.31 fixed the problem

Comment: Had same issue with Acer aspire 5740G. Was unable to upgrade bios from 1.22 to 1.28 from within win7 x86. Had to install win7 x64 first (I was planning to move to it anyway). Then I could update bios to 1.28. And connect second hdd