# Acer laptop won't load BIOS

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, bios

Have just cloned my HDD to SSD in my old Acer 7530g laptop (runs Ubuntu 16.04). dd worked just fine and didn't report any errors with the cloning. I swapped out the drives, but the laptop now freezes on the Acer logo screen. Pressing F2 doesn't go into BIOS. Pressing Esc shows me that the RAM, etc, is OK, but still won't let me get farther by pressing F2.

Things tried:

I've had the RAM in and out but that hasn't helped.

I've removed the SSD and powered the system on, and that will let me enter SETUP with F2, but it just loops through trying PXE, etc, and reports no OS can be found.

Put the SSD back in again and it won't let me enter setup.

It boots happily enough off the old HDD when I put that back in.

The new SSD is a 500gb, the old HDD was a 250gb, but I'm not thinking that would make a difference.

Any way to get the laptop to at least allow me to get to BIOS with the cloned SSD in it?

Comment: You might need to update your BIOS as suggested on the Related questions of this question. [Question 1](https://superuser.com/questions/632879/replaced-optical-drive-with-ssd-in-caddy-but-bios-freezes-acer-aspire-5740-584?rq=1), [Question 2](https://superuser.com/questions/698826/acer-travelmate-p253-m-freezes-on-bios?rq=1).

Comment: Will try, thank you. PS - links in Q2 (https://superuser.com/questions/698826/acer-travelmate-p253-m-freezes-on-bios?rq=1) are now 404s.

Comment: That's not your laptop model and that link is not from an official source, I will try to replace it if I find a driver.

Comment: Acer official pages have got appropriate BIOS for my machine: https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/support-product/121?b=1 (slight PITA with having to install a broken version and then immediately install the fix, though - might see if I can get away with the earlier version and skip the hassle)

Comment: Good then! Compare the versions to see if you got the latest firmware installed or not.

Comment: This is good advice, but I ended up just using a different laptop which tolerated the swap out without a bios update. If one of these comments becomes an answer I can accept it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to [update your BIOS](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/support-product/121?b=1) as suggested on the related questions of this question. [Question 1](https://superuser.com/questions/632879/replaced-optical-drive-with-ssd-in-caddy-but-bios-freezes-acer-aspire-5740-584?rq=1), [Question 2](https://superuser.com/questions/698826/acer-travelmate-p253-m-freezes-on-bios?rq=1).

I'm not sure what is the issue but those questions are all related to your problem and an update fixed both issues.

Be in mind that updating the BIOS is a advanced process and must be done carefully.

Also, compare the versions to see if you got the latest firmware installed or not.